# How can I fix my input shape for Conv1D? - Audio classification model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I keep getting the error that my input shape should have had 3 dimensions, but it has 2, and I don't know how to shuffle it to make it work. I've checked similar questions but here I'll display my specific problem.

My dataset is a series of .wav audio files, for which I have a path, and I've already matched with the corresponding word and MFCC.

I have a 75859 arrays, in which each array consists of 99 lists, in which each list has 13 values.

Here's my x_train:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],coeff, time_step)

len(x_train[1]) = 99

len(x_train[1][0]) = 13

x_train[1][0][0] = a single number i.e. 0.10

x_train.shape[0] = 75859
```

(I do trust my Conv1D model and so far I have no suspicions about it)

Here's the error I get:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_61_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (18965, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input_shape` parameter of the first layer of your neural network needs to correspond to the input. Set it to: `input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]`. If that doesn't work, update your post with you entire model architecture.